# AWS Elastic Beanstalk: Separate application loadbalancer config from .ebextensions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

As it is currently not possible to configure an application loadbalancer using the Elastic Beanstalk UI, I have managed configuring an ALB using .ebextensions/*.config files as described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-applicationloadbalancer.html

Unfortunately, this leads to my application bundle having all configuration including the ARN of AWS Certificate Manager hard coded, so my application bundle cannot be used for different domains / regions. How can I cleanly separate the application loadbalancer configuration from my application bundle, or is this the wrong approach at all?